# How to retrieve GitHub Java projects that import a specific Maven dependency?

Tags: maven, github, github-api

Is there a way to get access to a list of the Java projects in GitHub that import a given Maven dependency based on the contents of the `artifactId` or `groupId` tags?

For example, I wanna know which projects in GitHub are importing the dependency `<artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>` or `<groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>`.

Is it possible? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A crude first approximation would be a GitHub search with filename `pom.xml`:

```
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=aaaa+extension%3Axml+filename%3Apom.xml+language%3AXML&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=XML&l=
```

But you would need to inspect each result to see if the artifctId, for instance, is listed in the `<dependencies>` section.

You might also consider a [Google BigQuery](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bigquery-github/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0), done against the [GitHub public dataset](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/github/github-repos?filter=solution-type:dataset&pli=1), which includes a full snapshot of the content of more than 2.8 million open source GitHub repositories.

---

A more precise feature closed is [GitHub Dependency Graph](https://help.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/listing-the-packages-that-a-repository-depends-on), available for public project in supported languages (that includes Java/Maven)

You can [try its API](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/dependencygraphmanifest/) (in preview for now, see "[Access to a Repositories Dependency Graph](https://developer.github.com/v4/previews/#access-to-a-repositories-dependency-graph)"), but that would be project per project.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**

GitHub is available via [REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) - you can search for everything available in [advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced).

**Example**

[https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org.apache.jmeter+filename:pom.xml+path:/+repo:jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin](https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org.apache.jmeter%20filename:pom.xml%20path:/%20repo:jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin)

**Result**

```
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "pom.xml",
      ...
      "repository": {
        ...
        "full_name": "jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin",
```

**Details**

You cannot search for repositories by their content - this is API limitation. However you can [search for code](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code) in any way you like. And resolve repo info from the result.

Short example [is limited](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code) by a single repo. To get rid of this limitation and search across ALL public repositories you must [authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), either through basic authentication or with OAuth2 token.